# Read data from an encrypted /home directory

Tags: mount, home

I have changed my laptop's hard drive for a bigger one, and because the installation of elemmentary was corrupted somehow (didn't start the OS)

Now when I mount the hard drive as an external drive, I can't access the data inside the /home folder because it's encrypted, but I don't remember what is the password that I have set to that folder.

Is there any way to "break" the encryption of that folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you remember your login password?

Comment: I've used the answer given down below. It works perfectly but until now I couldn't mark it as a correct answer, sorry for any inconvenience and thanks!

Comment: Ok. So problem solved

Comment: Yes, luckily for me it was solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to "break" the encryption of that folder?

Yes, there is. This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption) here seems similar to yours.
You should also read the official Ubuntu Documentation about Encrypted /home folder, here: [Encrypted home folder](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome)

In order to decrypt a whole filesystem: [Mount encrypted volumes from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line) See the first answer.

Here is the official Ubuntu Documentation for mounting encrypted external filesystems: [EncryptedFilesystemsOnExternalStorage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage)

You should also read about LUKS(Linux Unified Key Setup), the disk encryption system in Linux. Here is a full detailed wiki on LUKS: [LUKS: Linux Unified Key Setup](https://github.com/guardianproject/luks/wiki)